# Can i set a default value without the new and create action and directly edit it using edit and update actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Users model and a Questions model. Each user has_one Question and each questions belongs_to a User. The Questions model has 3 columns - QuestionOne, QuestionTwo and QuestionThree - each is set to a default value of the string "TBD".

When the user creates an account and signs in I want to display on his profile the Questions and the responses = "TBD" and then using Best in place I want him to be able to edit his responses using the edit and update actions. But I cant retrieve the questions using `user.question.questionone` because they are sit to nil as there is no create or new action here. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# user.rb
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one      :question
  after_create :create_question

  def create_question
    question = self.build_question
    question.question_one = question.question_two = question.question_three = "TBD"
    question.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When new user is created, it does not have associated question yet, so you need to build it somehow. Common way is using ActiveRecord callbacks `before_create` or `after_create`, something like

```
# user.rb
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one      :question
  after_create :create_question
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can write a migration that add default questions whenever the question is created,

```
class ChangeDefaultQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :questions, :question_one,   :string, :default => 'What is your name?'
    change_column :questions, :question_two,   :string, :default => 'How old are you?'
    change_column :questions, :question_three, :string, :default => 'Where do you live'

    # to add default questions to previously created questions
    Questions.update_all({ :question_one => 'your qestion', :question_two => 'your question', :question_three => 'your question' })
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :movies, :rating, :string, :default => nil
    Questions.update_all({ :question_one => '', :question_two => '', :question_three => '' })
  end
end
```

i am sure it would answer your question